# Count words separated by comma and show them

Tags: google-sheets, count

I've tried splitting, counts, flatten and much more but I get errors.

I have a list of locations and grouped locations separated by comma. For example:

```
A1 - Europe, south Europe, Africa
A2 - United stages, East Europe, south Europe
A4- blank
A5 - Africa, United stages 
And so on.
```

I want to have a counter that will tell me how many times the countries appear, like this:

```
Europe 1
United stages 2
Africa 2
Etc
```

Also, it has to ignore blank cells because most successful try I've done counts them as errors and messes up my percentages.

Ideally this would show them up largest to smallest number, but this is the least of my worry here.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(TRIM(FLATTEN(IFERROR(SPLIT(A1:A; ",")))); 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  order by count(Col1) desc 
  label count(Col1)''"))
```

[image]